# Phonegap online Event wrong behavior on Iphone

Tags: cordova

has anyone experienced something like this. I have my callback functions and implement them like this.

```
function onBodyLoad()
    {
        $('.loading').bind('click',function(){
                           console.log("loading screen should show now");
                           $('#teaserslider').hide();
                           $('#resultslider').hide();
                           $('#loading-screen').show();
        })
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady(), false);


    }


    function onDeviceReady()
    {
        $('#loading-screen').hide();
        setUpDatabase();
        document.addEventListener("online", deviceIsOnline, false);
    }

    function deviceIsOnline(){
        alert("Im online!");
        if (true){
            persistResultHistory();
        }

    }
```

Connected to Wi-Fi, I get the ("Im online!") pop up 3 times. I searched my whole project, it only gets invoked here. So why 3 times? Also, when I switch on the airplane-mode without any connection to the internet, I get the pop-up 1 time. Anyone has experienced similar behavior?
Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you put the whole source code if possible?? also mention your phonegap and device version

Comment: i have changed your code slightly and now it fires only one time for me - https://gist.github.com/3077171

Comment: one obvious mistake in your code is `document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady(), false);`, this executes the function immediately, change it to `document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);`

Comment: woa, thanks for the information dhaval!

Comment: I just checked it (I`m at work now). Yes it works. What a mistake. The information is of very high value for me.

Comment: I will put it in the answer if you can accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the method immediately instead of giving reference of the method, so replace:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady(), false);
```

With

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
```

Also put the `addEventListener()` outside of the `onBodyLoad()` function and make it run immediately.

Full source code here - https://gist.github.com/3077171